# Nearby Selection Error with ChangeMoveSelector and NearbySelection

Tags: optaplanner

We are solving an allocation problem in OptaPlanner where each machine/period combination has a material allocated to it.
The planning entity has the machine/period key and its planning variable is a `private Material allocatedMaterial` field which represents a problem fact.
We understand that neighborhood search should help the optimizer focus on the vicinities of the planning entity - which is defined by a distance metric based on time/period distance.
Out aim is to narrow the entity search to the ones that are closest to the last entity that was changed.
We have set up the configuration below:

```
<changeMoveSelector>
    <entitySelector id="entitySelector1"/>
    <valueSelector>
        <nearbySelection>
            <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector1"/>
            <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>org.test.AllocationDistanceMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>                   
            <nearbySelectionDistributionType>
                    PARABOLIC_DISTRIBUTION</nearbySelectionDistributionType>
            <parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>40</parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>
        </nearbySelection>
    </valueSelector>
</changeMoveSelector>
```

With this configuration DistanceMeter:

1. The initial DistanceMeter call receives a null value for the destination
2. On the following calls the destination is interpreted as the problem fact instead of the planning entity (machine/period) and throws the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entitySelectorConfig (EntitySelectorConfig(null)) has a mimicSelectorRef (entitySelector1) for which no entitySelector with that id exists (in its solver phase).
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.selector.entity.EntitySelectorFactory.buildMimicReplaying(EntitySelectorFactory.java:132)
```

```
public class AllocationDistanceMeter implements NearbyDistanceMeter<EntityClass, EntityClass> {

    @Override
    public double getNearbyDistance(EntityClassorigin, EntityClassdestination) {
        return Math.abs(origin.period - destination.period);
    }

}
```

---

I have tried changing the ValueSelector to an EntitySelector. In that case I get the following error message:

`The entitySelectorConfig (EntitySelectorConfig(null)) has a mimicSelectorRef (entitySelector1) for which no entitySelector with that id exists (in its solver phase)`

Configuration with an EntitySelector:

```
<changeMoveSelector>
    <entitySelector id="entitySelector1">
        <nearbySelection>
            <originEntitySelector mimicSelectorRef="entitySelector1"/>
 <nearbyDistanceMeterClass>org.test.AllocationDistanceMeter</nearbyDistanceMeterClass>            <nearbySelectionDistributionType>PARABOLIC_DISTRIBUTION</nearbySelectionDistributionType>
            <parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>40</parabolicDistributionSizeMaximum>
        </nearbySelection>    
    </entitySelector>
</changeMoveSelector>
```

Is ChangeMoveSelector + Nearby Selection based on Entity Selection supported by OptaPlanner? If so, what is wrong with the configuration?

Comment: We're working on a feature to easily turn Nearby Selection with a single line in Timefold, to avoid config complexity like this. That being said, I am not sure why you're getting the first error message on first sight.